# The function sscanf_s fail when I use several strings

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, parsing, scanf

I don't understand why the code below fail :

```
char    toto[54], titi[54]; //I already tried with allocations

sscanf_s(line, "%s-%s", &toto, &titi, sizeof(toto) + sizeof(titi));
```

or

```
sscanf_s(line, "%s-%s", &toto, &titi, sizeof(toto) + sizeof(titi));
```

My problem is only with strings (float, int, double etc. its ok) and I use Visual 2010.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks a lot in advance for your answer.

Comment: In addition to other answers, &toto is of type char**. And toto is the char* pointer you need, like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx .

Comment: Is this C? There is nothing in the question that is C++.

Comment: retagged as C because it has nothing to do with C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`sscanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) reference page:

> The sscanf_s function reads data from buffer into the location given by each argument. The arguments after the format string specify pointers to variables with a type that corresponds to a type specifier in format. **Unlike the less secure version sscanf, a buffer size parameter is required when using the type field characters c, C, s, S and [. The buffer size in characters must be supplied as an additional parameter after each buffer which requires it.** For more information, see scanf_s, _scanf_s_l, wscanf_s, _wscanf_s_l and scanf Type Field Characters.

Meaning each buffer must be followed by its size:

```
sscanf_s(line, "%s-%s", toto, sizeof(toto), titi, sizeof(titi));
```

Additionally, `-` is not a whitespace character will not act as a terminator for `"%s"` format specifier so if `line` contained `hello-world` then it would be read into `toto` and `titi` would not be assigned. To use `-` as a terminator use a scan set:

```
if (2 == sscanf_s(line, "%[^-]-%s", toto, sizeof(toto), titi, sizeof(titi)))
{
    /* Both 'toto' and 'titi' where assigned. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless `sscanf_s()` is distincly weird, you don't want to pass a pointer to the array (`&toto`) but a pointer to the first element of the array (`toto`). Also, the goal of the secure functions is to avoid buffer overruns, i.e., you need to specify for each individual buffer how many characters it contains:

```
if (sscanf_s(line, "%s-%s", toto, sizeof(toto), titi, sizeof(titi)) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

(error handling because attempts to read should always check whether an error occured before processing the data)

Personally, I would use an `std::istringstream` together with strings and a suitable custom manipulator and avoid the issue entirely:

```
std::istream& minus(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() != std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type('-')) {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    else {
        in.ignore();
    }
    return in;
}

std::string toto, titi;
if (std::istringstream(line) >> std::skipws >> toto >> minus >> titi)) {
    ...
}
```